# Why does 9/2 gives 4 as an output while using double in java

Tags: java, integer, double

Why [**double divide_ = 9 / 2;**] gives output of 4.0? while [**double divide = (double) 9 / 2**] gives an output of 4.5?

Comment: the division is NOT using `double`, just the result is being assigned to the  `double` || specified in [JLS 15.17. Multiplicative Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17-320): "* If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic is performed.*"

Comment: Use the float type

Comment: BTW code is formatted  by using single back-ticks ` around it or, for multi-line code, using 3 (or more) back-ticks on a line before and after the code (or indenting the code by at least 4 spaces)